"Most of what I've seen were foreign programs" VS "Most of what I've seen have been foreign programs"

Most of what I've seen were foreign programs.
Most of what I've seen have been foreign programs.

I've made up these two sentences and wonder if both of them are correct.
The first sentence uses were even though there's no past time stamp.
The second uses have seen and then have been, which sounds a bit repetitive to me.
So, which one is better or are they equally okay? Is there a better way to say this?

The most natural is the present, … is foreign programs.

Choice of tense depends on the tense(s) used in surrounding sentences. What are you talking about?

We endlessly see such constructed examples of tense choices that serve only to show that the questioner has done little or any research of their own.

My criticism (and the reason for the downvote) is that absent context the question is really a waste of everyone's time.  Are you referring to your TV watching habits?  Your search for a summer language program? What?  Reality can have bearing upon how we use language.

Both versions of the sentence are grammatical and idiomatic.If there's any difference, "were" suggests that "foreign programs" have been dismissed as an option whereas "have been" suggests they are still under consideration.
But absent context, what you mean by "seen" and "programs" is really just a guess on my part.

The narrative is about something current, and the nature of the programs (foreign) doesn't change.  I'd say

Most of what I've seen are foreign programs.

The past tense 'were foreign programs'
is possible if the narrative is about
a past event.  The backshifting (optional)
enables us to use were if we want to:

Most of what I saw were foreign programs.

There's no reason to use 'have been foreign programs'.

I believe, Most of what I've seen have been foreign programs, can refer to a broader idea and choice in your life experiences, including anything you've seen.
The first option, however, can be more exclusive and related to a specific time period.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
